# What will happen if I send a SYN packet to the server when there has already been a TCP connection established?

Tags: tcp

The SYN packet has the same source dest IP address & port with the established connection, so what will happen in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will silently drop the packet since it already has a connection in the ESTABLISHED state, one of the four values from (client-ip, src-port, server-ip, dest-port) must be different for the new SYN to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The server will attempt a new connection.
in tech terms it will send a syn,ack packet and wait for the client to finish the tcp handshake 
and open the connection.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
will explain the process alot better than me.

the server will send some information to identify the connection in its syn,ack packet.
and that information is used to keep that connection seperate from others.

Most the time, the ports will not be the same
but when it is, it can cause problems with low grade nat routers,
They try to rewrite that ports that are used, and can get the connections confused.

Comment: -1 Server does not "send some information" in any packet to identify the connection. For the same client, the source port has to be different to establish a new connection. The only way to identify a TCP connection is by a unique 4-tuple (client-ip, src-port, server-ip, dest-port).

Comment: I reread the wiki page again and stand corrected, Jaidev is correct