# TCP connection SYN packets being ignored, zero window size?

Tags: http, tcp

I have an embedded device running an http client. Until now we have always used linux servers but recently have needed to use windows servers and am now having issues.

My device opens a connection sends some data and then closes it ( not neccessarily gracefully as a reset or power failure can occur anytime!).
What im finding is that after a few days at some locations only the server stops accepting new connections from the device.
Originally I thought this might be due to trying to open a connection on already estabilished port as here: [What will happen if I send a SYN packet to the server when there has already been a TCP connection established?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825036/what-will-happen-if-i-send-a-syn-packet-to-the-server-when-there-has-already-bee)
but now that I randomize the initial port value after boot up the issue still occurs (I would also expect the old connection to timeout).

I have noticed several things that look strange:
The SYN packet has a zero window size and a zero length, is this correct?
It also has a zero sequence number, I think this is right?

I apologize for lack of detail, I may be able to put up a link to a Wireshark capture at some point. The windows servers we are dealing with are also in 'the cloud' so I have very little in the way of access to server logs (which I find a bit ridiculous).

Comment: The device's behaviour about what's in the SYN packet can't be different because it's sending to a different server operating system, can it? It's starting the exchange: at that point it knows nothing about the target at all. You're going to have to provide a capture.

Comment: An update, turns out that the zero window size and length were an error in the operating system

Comment: An update, turns out that the zero window size (length and sequence ar correct at zero I think) were an error in the operating systems TCP/IP stack. Some O/S and more importantly some routers/switches do reject these packets. Unfortunately I dont think this was related to my problem.